# Adding an item to the Context Menu

Tags: android, contextmenu, contacts

I wish to add an option of 'SEND' to the context menu of Contacts. Is it possible to extend the ContextMenu Activity? or is there any other option for the same?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to extend the ContextMenu Activity?

`ContextMenu` is not an `Activity`, and you cannot modify the context menu of another application.