# add menu item to android applicaton

Tags: android, menuitem

Is it possible to have something similar like Blackberry in Android:
[link text](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Create_a_menu_item_602617_11.jsp)

I want to add a menu item particularly to the Contacts Option menu.

please let me know if this can be done in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you specify more clearly what you're trying to achieve / where you want to add the menu.

The menu that appears when you press the menu button on BB is equivalent to the menu options that come up when you press the menu button on Android.

Talking about the Contact application on Android, this would be the menu with the menu items "Search, Display options, Get Friends, My Profile, ..." in the Contact app's list view.

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html

Comment: Hi Lin, Thanks for responding. i want when first time my application starts it should add a menu item to the already existing option menu of contact application, something like say 'launch my activity". so when user browse to the contact application and press the menu button it should display the menu item "launch my activity" alongside the existing options and when user click on it, it should launch my logic that i want to execute on that click. i know this can be done in blackberry thats why i posted that link what i want to know is whether it can be done in android or not.

Comment: I see. I don't think you can add a menu item to another application that's not yours. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615772/adding-an-item-to-the-context-menu